# Which version of ruby and rails should I start my app with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to start developing a new app and I am confused with which version of ruby and rails to use. Anyone please suggest stable versions of ruby and rails which have good documentation and are compatible with most of the gems.

Comment: If you're looking for us to give you specific version numbers, we can't. That isn't how Stack Overflow works, and such a question should be closed immediately as "too localized". The only answer we can give you is that you should use whatever the latest current stable version of Rails is, as listed on http://rubyonrails.org/download. We can't possible answer your questions about gem compatibility if you won't even give us which gems you're worried about, as it's impossible to find any version of Rails which works with every Gem ever written.

Comment: @meagar I know that there is no version of rails which works with every gem that's why I mentioned(most of gems) in comment of your answer.

Comment: No one knows "most of the gems", so as far as being able to help, it's fundamentally equivalent to "all gems". The best we might be able to think about is "popular gems", but if they're popular, they'll have lots of support and the Rub and RoR versions will be less important.

Comment: "Most gems" which are worth using will work with the newest version of Rails, so as I've said repeatedly, use the latest version of Rails. There is nothing more to say on the topic. There is absolutely no reason to use anything else unless you can tell us about a *specific gem* which you absolutely have to use which only works with an older version of Rails.

Answer (score 7):

Please refer to  [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Its the best place to start with.

Start with http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And this [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book)

You will come to know how to move forward.

Comment: Rails guide will give the details of how to use that particular version of rails. But my problem is with gems. Newer version of rails doesn't support most of gems. So can u suggest some stable Rails 3 which supports most of gems.

Comment: Newer versions of Rails support any gems that you actually want to use. Use the latest version of Rails. It's way, way more important to get the newest core functionality than it is to get support for outdated gems.

Answer (score 2):

Either figure out where you'll be hosting your app and what they provide, *or*, build using the latest Ruby/Rails versions and then seek out a host which supports those versions.

Comment: Hosting is not a issue for me. Because I am not doing that now. It will take long time to host. I am just worrying of support of gem. Recent version creates lots of issue with gems. So Any stable rails 3 version can u suggest me.

Comment: The latest Rails 3 version. Do a `gem install rails` and use whatever version it brings in.